# How to display Talairach Image in AFNI correctly?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, philosophy-of-mind, fmri

I am using AFNI to display Talairach image, that is `anat+tlrc.BRIK & anat+tlrc.HEAD` . But the AFNI only shows part of the image. It looks like this:

[image]

AFNI is one of the softwares to display and analyze fMRI images. I am sure that the Talairach image I want to display is in correct format.  I do not how to fix this problem? Anyone can give me a help?